# Paper unfolding with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have tried to unfold a sheet of paper in CSS and HTML, but these technologies are not my strong point.

I would like to make a sheet folded in 3 parts unfold vertically.

I will try to explain with a design (in the bottom of the question) what I am trying to obtain.
Note that face 1 is slightly overlapping face 2, so face one should open slightly before face two.

It would be ideal if I could place images on all the faces so that I can fill them with what I need.

[image: See here the design of the need :)]

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
}

.rolo-w {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.top:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.top:hover #f2_card {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face.front {
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/futuristic-glass-business-card-vector-id1307055177?s=612x612);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.face.back {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Redsquare.png?20180330145031);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  display: block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="rolo-w">
    <div id="f1_card">
      <div class="front face"> </div>
      <div class="back face center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="top2">
  <div class="rolo-w2">
    <div id="f1_card2">
      <div class="front2 face2"> </div>
      <div class="back2 face2 center2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Victor can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: Sure!  I will update the post!

Comment: also please read the description of the tags you using. This question has nothing to do with `unfold`

Comment: @innocent post updated with some of my tests

Comment: your css codes not enough

Comment: Do you want the viewer to be face on to the sheet of paper or do you want them to be slightly to one side?

Comment: Updated my solution below

Answer (score 0):

I loved the challenge, you were already close.

I have added another card element in the middle and a single top `<div>` element.

I also added shorter and more descriptve CSS class names for clarity.

The result might not be perfect but it should definitely help you.

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  height: 50vh;
}

.rolo-w {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

#f1_card{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


#f1_card1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.6s linear;
  transform-origin: top;
}

#f1_card2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.6s linear;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.top:hover #f1_card1 {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.top:hover #f1_card2 {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.back {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Redsquare.png?20180330145031);
}

.front {
  background: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/futuristic-glass-business-card-vector-id1307055177?s=612x612);
}

.rotate {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Redsquare.png?20180330145031);
  display: block;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
 
  <div class="rolo-w">
<div id="f1_card">
 
  <div class="face back"></div>
</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rolo-w">
<div id="f1_card1">
  <div class="face front"> </div>
  <div class="face rotate"></div>
</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rolo-w">
<div id="f1_card2">
  <div class="face front"> </div>
  <div class="face rotate"></div>
</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```